# Use FoldList to successively ImageAdd regular polygons with between 3 and 8 sides, and with opacity 0.2

Tags: graphics, pure-function, nested-function

This question is from [Section 29 of *"An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language"*](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/29-more-about-pure-functions.html).

The objective is to successively add regular polygons with between 3 and 8 sides, and with opacity 0.2, using the commands [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) and [`ImageAdd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdd.html) and using pure functions.

My attempts (multiple attempts, none working out) went something like this:

```
FoldList[ImageAdd, {Graphics[Opacity[0.2],{RegularPolygon[#]}]}&/@{3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

Or

```
FoldList[ImageAdd[#1,#2]&,#1&, Graphics[{Opacity[0.2],RegularPolygon[]}]
```

Both are unfinished code as I didn't know how to execute this properly, but I wanted to show the general idea I was attempting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `FoldList[ImageAdd, 
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.2], RegularPolygon[#]}] & /@ {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: `https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/answers-to-exercises.html`